# Popup div containing Textarea when clicking a table cell

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am by no means an expert with `jquery` or `css`. I am trying to achieve a functionality in my application, which I have not been able to.

I have a text area in one of the table cells that is supposed to hold notes or description. I want to be able to pop-up a larger size of the textarea when a user clicks inside it. The user would enter the information and say, click an "X" button, say, on the top right corner of the cell, that will restore the textarea to it's original size.

Here is the HTML page code and the accompanying CSS and jquery that I have tried with, so far. Any ideas or suggestions would be tremendously helpful.

Best regards

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style>
    th, td {
        border: solid 1px lightgrey;
    }

    #div_id {     
      display:none;
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
    }

    #div_id textarea {
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 3px solid #cccccc;
      padding: 5px;
      font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }

  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#cell_id').click(function(){
      
        alert("hello");
        $("#div_id").style.display = "block";
        $('#div_id').toggle('slow');
      
      });


    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="left" style="margin-top:5px; border: solid #666 1px;">
    <table id="itemtable" class="" style="width: 300px; margin: 10px;">
      <thead style="color:black;">
        <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Part Desc</th>                     
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> 2001</td>
          <td> Toyota</td>
          <td id='cell_id' onclick=''>test</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="div_id"><textarea name='reqnotes'>123</textarea></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the textarea is `toggled` when you click on `part desc` and shows `123` - you want textrea to be bigger and have `X` to close it ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, Thank you for taking a look at this.  Yes, I want the textarea to be bigger (say, 200px X 300px, so user is able to see the contents. And yes, I am looking to have an X to close it. Thanks, again!

Comment: I have added a solution below to meet your needs as exactly you wanted as per the comment above.

Comment: Thank you, very much! Yes, indeed, it works exactly as expected. I can now expand on your solution to fit into my code.

Comment: Nice. Glad to hear that and Happy to helped you!. Let me know if i can help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some custom `CSS` and `jQuery` [slideToggle](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) function to have some effects when you click on `part Desc` it will show the textarea.

In the `textarea` i have added a `span` which is out **`X`** button which will be used to close the `textarea` div when needed.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Show textarea
  $('#cell_id').click(function() {
    $('#div_id').slideToggle('slow');
  });
  
  //Close textarea
  $('#close_text').click(function() {
    $('#div_id').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px lightgrey;
}

#div_id {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

#div_id textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#close_text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #cfd0d1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>

  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="left" style="margin-top:5px; border: solid #666 1px;">
    <table id="itemtable" class="" style="width: 300px; margin: 10px;">
      <thead style="color:black;">
        <tr>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Part Desc</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> 2001</td>
          <td> Toyota</td>
          <td id='cell_id' onclick=''>test</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="div_id"><textarea name='reqnotes'>123</textarea>
      <span id="close_text" title="Click to close">X</span></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```